# The command aborts unexpectedly while entering a line through the cin.getline function

Tags: c++, input, struct, getline

The command aborts unexpectedly while entering a line through the cin.getline function

3
Manchester United
2
Ronaldo Portugal
Rooney England
Everton
2
Rooney England
Barkley England
Real Madrid
3
Figo Portugal
Ronaldo Portugal
Bale Wales
Portugal

Output:
Manchester United
Real Madrid

```
using namespace std;

struct footballer {
    string footballer_name;
    char* country = new char;
};

struct club {
    char* club_name = new char[10001];
    int footballersCount;
    footballer* footballers;
};


int main(){
    int number_of_clubs;
    cin >> number_of_clubs;
    struct club struct_club[1001];
    struct footballer struct_footballer[100][100];
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_clubs; i++) {
        cin.getline(struct_club[i].club_name, 256);
        cin >> struct_club[i].footballersCount;
        for (int j = 0; j < struct_club[i].footballersCount; j++) {
            cin >> struct_footballer[i][j].footballer_name >> struct_footballer[i][j].country;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_clubs; i++) {
        cout << struct_club[i].club_name << endl;
        cout << struct_club[i].footballersCount << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < struct_club[i].footballersCount; j++) {
            cout << struct_footballer[i][j].footballer_name << " " << struct_footballer[i][j].country << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty odd mix of `std::string` (`footballer_name`), single characters by mistake (`country`), and unnecessarily large arrays (`club_name`). Are you trying various things to see what happens?

Comment: You don't have much code here so sitting down and discussing all of it line by line with [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) isn't unreasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have to use cin.ignore() everytime you use cin.getline() after cin>> because cin>> leaves the new line ch in buffer.
Just add cin.ignore(); as a first line when you enter your first loop.